Reverse Markov inequality
Let $C > c > 0$ and $K > 1$ be constants. Does there exist, for all small enough $\varepsilon > 0$ depending on $c, C, K$, some bound of the following form?

For all random variables $X$ with $c \leq \mathbb E[X^2] \leq C$ and $E[|X|] \leq \varepsilon c^{\frac{1}{2}}$, we have
$$\mathbb P\left (|X| \geq K \mathbb E[|X|] \right ) \geq \delta \mathbb E[|X|]^2$$
for some constant $\delta > 0$ depending only on $c, C, K, \varepsilon$.

Upon some googling, it would seem if we allow $K < 1$, then this is the Paley Zygmund inequality. I wonder if it can be improved to arbitrarily large $K$ in this scenario.

Replace $X$ by $X / \sqrt{c}$ you get rid of one constant that you need to quantify over.

@an_ordinary_mathematician ah, you are right. This needs to be refined more if there is really anything here... will delete the post shortly once I confirm you have recieved this.

@an_ordinary_mathematician Uh, actually I think I found the fix... would you mind if I edited the post?

sure no problem , I will delete the comment

@an_ordinary_mathematician I am confused, $\delta$ was allowed to depend on $C$, $c$ and $\varepsilon$, so your example is not a counterexample (in it $\varepsilon \to 0$). Anyways, the answer to the original question is no for any $K \ge 1$, I will now type an answer.

Well, but all functions satisfy the hypothesis for a fixed epsilon

Ah, there were an inequality. Mea culpa.

Note that there is a stronger (than Payley-Zygmund) reverse Markov inequality known. See lemma 3.7.

As you noticed, for $K < 1$ (some form of) it is true. I will show that it is false for $K \ge 1$. It is enough to construct functions $f_n$ on $[0, 1]$ with  $\int |f_n| = \varepsilon$ and $\int |f_n|^2=1$ for some $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, such that $|\{ x: |f_n(x)| \ge 1\}| \le \gamma_n$, where $\gamma_n \to 0$. Indeed, the function $f_n$ would only take two values: on $[0, 1-1/n]$ it will be equal to $a$ and on $(1-1/n, 1]$ it will be equal to $b$. We have
$$\begin{cases}a(1-1/n) + b/n = \varepsilon,\\ a^2(1-1/n)+b^2/n = 1.\end{cases}$$
From the first equation $b = n\varepsilon - a(n-1)$, plugging this into the second one we get a quadratic equation, which I was taught how to solve in middle school. We have (I chose the smaller root)
$$a = \varepsilon - \frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon^2(n-1)^2-(n-1)(\varepsilon^2 n - 1)}}{(n-1)},$$
from which we get $0 < a < \varepsilon$ as long as $\varepsilon^2 n > 1$ and also in this case $b > \varepsilon$. Now it is clear that our function is bigger than $\varepsilon=\int |f_n|$ only on the set of measure $\frac{1}{n}$.

$+1$, though you should not say "Indeed", since that makes it seem like you are justifying the previous sentence (about why "it is enough").

Huh, I only learnt it in high school. Nice solution!

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$Here is a version of Alexei's answer which is arguably more transparent (and does not require solving quadratic equations :-)).
Take any $\ep\in(0,1)$ and then any $a\in(0,\ep)$. Let $b:=\ep+\dfrac1{\ep-a}>\ep$. Let $P(X=b)=\dfrac{\ep-a}{b-a}$ and $P(X=a)=1-P(X=b)=\dfrac{b-\ep}{b-a}$. Then $EX=\ep$, $EX^2=1+\ep^2\in[1,2]$, and for any $K\ge1$
$$P(X\ge K\,EX)\le P(X\ge EX)=\dfrac{\ep-a}{b-a}\to0$$
if $a\uparrow\ep$.
So, for any $K\ge1$, the best lower bound on $P(X\ge K\,EX)$ is $0$.
